how to block only current active thread when using java remote debugging in intellij idea
I am using Inetllij Idea to remote debug the java application, at first when I set the debug point, it will block the whole JVM and make the whole application unavailable. Then I change the break point to thread like this:

this will also block the application, then i tried to tweak the setting resume only current thread like this:

in spring boot application, this will block the controller rest request, when the first request hit the break point, the send same request will blocked. But other request works fine. is it possible to block the current thread, when the next same request reach, just pass without block. in other words, just block the one thread that current hit.
